# C2512 Error - Even when not initializing class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm a little lost here. I have a member of type "CLuaHook" in my class "CLuaTick" which I plan to use in the CLuaTick::Initialize() function. Because of the Linker I have to declare my member in the cpp file, although im not entirely sure why. Setting the member declaration in the cpp to a nullptr causes a runtime crash (Access violation) even though its not used anywhere yet.

The only constructor for CLuaHook is `CLuaHook(const char * Hook);`.

**EDIT**: CLuaHook() *Has* to be called with valid arguments as it will be registered in an Internal list and would have to be removed afterwards.

Heres the code:
**luatick.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "LuaSrc\lua.h"
#include "LuaHook.h"

class CLuaTick
{
private:
    static CLuaHook m_Hook;

public:
    static void Initialize(lua_State *State);
};
```

**luatick.cpp**

```
#include "LuaTick.h"

CLuaHook CLuaTick::m_Hook;

void CLuaTick::Initialize(lua_State * State)
{
    m_Hook = CLuaHook("Tick");
}
```

The error I'm receiving:

> Error  C2512   'CLuaHook': no appropriate default constructor    luatick.cpp

Comment: `CLuaHook` doesn't have a default constructor, then `CLuaHook CLuaTick::m_Hook;` won't work. You have to pass the argument to it, like `CLuaHook CLuaTick::m_Hook = CLuaHook(nullptr);`.

Comment: I actually added that line to calm the Linker. I only want to use that member once and assign it when Initialize is being called, how do I achieve that?

Comment: You might consider using [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to wrap it, i.e. a `std::optional<CLuaHook>` or `std::unique_ptr<CLuaHook>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very much as the compiler describes. There is no default constructor for the class `CLuaHook`. In other words, the compiler doesn't know how to construct `CLuaHook` with no arguments and therefore it can't construct `CLuaTick` either.

You need to either provide a default constructor:

```
CLuaHook() { ... set string to default value here ... }
```

Or you need to provide a default string when you initialise it in your cpp:

```
CLuaHook CLuaTick::m_Hook("Default Text");
```

Comment: Okay but does it actually spawn an object? Is the constructor actually being called? If so can I just overwrite it when I assign a proper value to it in ::Initialize() ?

Comment: @Flowx Yes the constructor is being called and an object is created. And yes you can change the properties of this object you either by providing interface functions to do so, or by reassigning the variable to a different object later on. Depending on the content of CLuaHook you may need to provide a copy constructor.

Comment: I would prefer to not touch m_Hook at all until initialize() is being called, but that causes a linker error for some reason. Is this possible?

Comment: @Flowx Then you would need to use some kind of pointer mechanism which you initialise when you want it. As @songyuanyao commented on the original question, you could consider `std::unique_ptr<CLuaHook>`

Comment: So the main issue here is that im using a reference instead of a pointer? Will this remove that extra line in cpp file for the linker?

Comment: @Flowx You are not "using a reference"; this is not Java!